# Java Apache HttpPost, setEntity replace or append

Tags: java, apache, replace, append, http-post

in HttpPost, this appends to the header

```
httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", "AFHttpClient/1.0");
        httppost.setHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

where each `setHeader` simply adds to the header, instead of replacing the header with a new header

I am wondering about the `setEntity` method.

Does calling the setEntity method sequentially simply add and append data to the entity, or replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `HttpPost#setEntity(HttpEntity)` just sets the entity, and overwrites it if you call it again. [See the source code of `HttpPost'](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.4/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.java#HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.setEntity%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29).

I don't think, `HTTP/1.1` allows transferring multiple entities.

Note also, that `HttpPost#setHeader(String, String)` will also overwrite the header, if you call it again with same header name and different value (See [`HeaderGroup#updateHeader(Header)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.4/org/apache/http/message/HeaderGroup.java#HeaderGroup.updateHeader%28org.apache.http.Header%29)).